# Problem with netbeans building ROS package

Tags: ros, ide, build, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick, install ros electric. I wish to use IDE to develop ros package, so I decided to use netbeans IDE. I have follow the http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs to configure the netbeans, but I fail to build and clean the project. The following is the output from the debug window of the Netbeans.

"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Default.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .clean-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/jun/NetBeansProjects/microstrain_3dmgx2_imu_1' cd /opt/ros/electric/stacks/imu_drivers/microstrain_3dmgx2_imu && /usr/bin/make -f Makefile clean cd: 1: can't cd to build make[2]: [clean] Error 2 (ignored) make[2]: Entering directory` /opt/ros/electric/stacks/imu_drivers/microstrain_3dmgx2_imu'
cd build && make clean
rm -rf build
make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/electric/stacks/imu_drivers/microstrain_3dmgx2_imu' make[1]: Leaving directory` /home/jun/NetBeansProjects/microstrain_3dmgx2_imu_1'

CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 240ms)
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Default.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
mkdir: cannot create directory `build': Permission denied make[2]: *** [all] Error 1 make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2 make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2 make[1]: Entering directory` /home/jun/NetBeansProjects/microstrain_3dmgx2_imu_1'
cd /opt/ros/electric/stacks/imu_drivers/microstrain_3dmgx2_imu && /usr/bin/make -f Makefile
make[2]: Entering directory `/opt/ros/electric/stacks/imu_drivers/microstrain_3dmgx2_imu' make[2]: Leaving directory` /opt/ros/electric/stacks/imu_drivers/microstrain_3dmgx2_imu'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/jun/NetBeansProjects/microstrain_3dmgx2_imu_1'

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 86ms)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11326/problem-with-netbeans-building-ros-package/) by [Jun](https://answers.ros.org/users/1127/jun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-09-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
Check this question, I think your problem is related:
http://answers.ros.org/question/318/sudo-rosmake-permission-denied-problem

regards

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2011-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2012-02-21**:
As @Procópio Silveira Stein suggested, this issue should be rooted in that `Netbeans` (or whatever process. Basically this issue shouldn't be specific for `Netbeans`) tries to write to the folder where it doesn't have a permission to do so. See the link if you have no idea for workaround.